# How to fix my Flutter App with Firebase Authentification

Tags: flutter, firebase

When I do `flutter run` I get the following error:

```
:\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-3.4.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java:66: error: package TransactionOptions does not exist
            new TransactionOptions.Builder().setMaxAttempts(maxAttempts).build(),
```

In my pubspec.yaml I have the newest version of the requried Firebase packages.

Does anyone know what  to do about this?
Thanks!

Comment: try with `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: Did you try to run flutter clean? if not try it and then run flutter run again

Comment: @YeasinSheikh doesn't work. The error only occurs when running the App with Firebase